# No users can log in with password

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've got a production site with three users, two of which are admins. None are able to log in with their password; They get "Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?" We ARE able to log in by requesting a new password and getting a temporary login key, so I'm able to access the administration pages and look at the unhelpful logs, but of course this is not sustainable.

I've tried:

- logging in on various devices
- clearing the cache
- running update.php
- adding a $cookie_domain in settings.php
- checking the database to make sure the users exist (they do, with hashed passwords)

My .htaccess file reroutes all traffic to https://www.

Core is Drupal 7.59.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you check if `$base_url` is set ?

Comment: I set it to https www example com; no help.

Comment: Check if user accounts are ok. I.e. they are not blocked or something.
Also, when you access admin pages try creating some new admin account and login with it.

Comment: Thanks, Milan. All of the users are listed as Active. I tried creating an Example Admin user and logging in with it -- same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Drupal 7 module "Hide Node Field." When I deactivated that module, user logins began working again. I will file a bug report with the Hide Node Field developers.